# Volume of a solid disk generated by rotating a plane

Tags: calculus

I am asked for computing the volume of a solid shaped-disk generated by rotating the finite plane region R which is limited by the curve $y=x^2$ and the line $y=1$. The solid rotates around $y=2$.

Having this graph

[image]

I defined the integral as follows:

$v = \pi\int_{0}^{1}(y_{2}-2)^2-(y_{1}-2)^2dx$

Where $y_{2}=x^2$ and $y_{1}=1$

The issue here is that I did it by analogy with another similar problem, and I do not understand why we have to integrate the difference $(y_{2}-2)^2-(y_{1}-2)^2$ in order to get the volume. Could you please shed some light on it?

Thanks

Comment: An integral is the limit of a sum of some sort. Can you think of a sum of volumes that approximates the volume of the object you are trying to measure? Can you divide the object you are trying to measure into objects whose volume you can approximate?

Comment: I thought about how to obtain the disk. What I did was $\pi x^{4}dx$ but does not match with the method of my analogue problem

Comment: the object you are trying to calculate the volume of is *not* a disk. If I had to describe the shape colloquially, I would describe it as a wedding ring. Can you divide that object into objects whose volume you can appproximate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we take your region and break it up into little rectangles, like we do for "normal" Riemann integration of a region in a plane.

Now we rotate each of those rectangles about the axis $y=2$

Each rectangle sweeps out a little disk with a hole in the center -- a washer.

And the volume of this washer is $\pi(R^2 - r^2)\ dx$  With R as the radius of the disk and $r$ as the radius of the hole.

or $R = (2-x^2)$ and $r = 1$

And then we sum the volume of these washers.

$$\pi \int_{-1}^1 (2-x^2)^2 - 1 \ dx$$

Comment: Okey thank you I see it better now. One question, why the radius of the disk is $R = (2 - y^{2})$?

Comment: @JD_PM  Sorry,  I had a mistake (now fixed).  But, the distance from the curve $y = x^2$ to $y= 2$ is $(2-x^2)$